# Java Keytool for SSL: CSR Aliases, Keys and Keystores

Tags: java, ssl

I read [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3pbP-7lx-c) article on how to use `keytool` to generate CSRs for your organization. It was simple and easy, but left me with a few questions that I couldn't find clear, descriptive answers to:

- What is Java's concept of a CSR `alias` and why would you want to use one? Where is this alias field stored and what other tools/APIs have access to it?
- What is the difference between a `key` and a `keystore`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### *What is Java's concept of a CSR alias and why would you want to use one? Where is this alias field stored and what other tools/APIs have access to it?*

First of all, java uses *keystores* to keep *keys* (and *certificates*) inside. Single *keystore* can hold many certificates, so you need a way to differentiate them. That's what *aliases* are for. Having a *keystore*, an *alias* (and a password if needed) you can get the *certificate* from the *keystore* using [Java Crypto API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html) (specifically classes like [`Keystore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html)). Here, you have a an [example of how the Crypto API can be used to load a key from keystore](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/RetrievingaKeyPairfromaKeyStore.htm)

#### *What is the difference between a key and a keystore?*

The *keystore* is a container. The *keys* are kept inside *keystores*.

Answer (score 2):

A keystore is a file format used to hold certificates and private keys, and alias is used to identify each entry in the keystore.